# Output of this program is 64. Can someone explain how?

Tags: c, math, io

```
#define sqr(a) a*a
int main()
{
int i;
i = 64 / sqr(4); //answer of this expression is 64.
printf("%d", i);
return 0;
}
```

In this code the output is 64, and according to the rules, the expression `i = 64 / sqr(4)` should be solved as `i = 64 / 4*4`, which gives a result of 4, but the output of the program is 64. Why?

Comment: 64 / 4 = 16 * 4 = 64. You have no parenthesis around the operation in your macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to keep this answer simple:

---

Macros is a set of code that just get **replaced** at the time of compilation.
Now, if you *replace* **sqr(4)** with **4*4**
It becomes something like: **64/4*4**.
Now, if you apply basic rule of BODMAS. It gets executed as follows:
**64/4= 16
16*4= 64** 
i.e first division with 4 then multiplication with 4 that gives 64

Answer (score 3):

Macros are not evaluated like functions, they are expanded in place.  The statement

```
i = 64 / sqr(4);
```

expands to

```
i = 64 / 4*4;
```

Both of the multiplication and division operators have the same precedence and are left-associative, so the above statement is parsed as

```
i = (64 / 4) * 4;
```

Thus, you are multiplying the result of `64 / 4` by `4`, rather than dividing `64` by the result of `4 * 4`.

They way to avoid precedence and associativity issues with macros like this is to enclose the expansion in parentheses:

```
#define sqr(a) (a * a)
```

By itself, though, that’s not sufficient - if you do something like `sqr(1+2)`, that will expand to `(1+2*1+2)`, which evaluates to `5` instead of the expected `9`.  You also need to parenthesize the argument(s) as well as the overall expression:

```
#define sqr(a) ((a) * (a))
```

Now your statement expands to

```
i = 64 / ((4) * (4));
```

and will evaluate to what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the order of operations.  Multiplication is done first, so it meant `(64 * 4) / 4`.  Here's an updated version with parenshases around your macro:

```c
#define sqr(a) ((a)*(a))
int main()
{
int i;
i = 64 / sqr(4); //answer of this expression is 4.
printf("%d", i);
return 0;
}
```